# PHP Header : Content-disposition: attachment , then Location: some url

Tags: php

My goal is to redirect browser to a new page after browser issues the attachment download.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv");
// csv output logic here

// forward to next page
header("Location: $url");
```

Is it possible ?

**UPDATE** : the result of above

The last line of CSV shows PHP error :

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

It is because CSV logic part has modified the contents before the line `header("Location: $url");`

**UPDATE** : I tried an alternative method: to echo a small HTML consist of a key line `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=$url" />` ( of course `<html>` `<head>` `<body>` and even DOCTYPE are also echoed ). But still, the HTML codes are shown in the CSV content.

Comment: did you try it? you know your goal, you have the code, what happened?

Comment: of course I tested, error `PHP header has already sent`. I will update the question shortly

Comment: @tradyblix question updated. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current code, no you can't. 
You force the browser to download the further content to file.csv so newer headers are ignored.

However, have a look at meta refresh stuff. You will be able to add a delay between the page load (so user actually sees a web page) and send the file to download in the refresh.

<strike>I wish I could add an example but I'm currently in a train surrounded by some babies crying and I'm bored.</strike>

To prevent the meta tags (and other HTML) appearing in the CSV file content, we can use some $_GET value.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['dl']) && $_GET['dl'] == '1') {
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv");
// csv output logic here
}
else{
?>
web page here, with html, head, title, body, and whatnot tags. 
In the head tag, add this:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://my.web.site.com/download.php?dl=1"> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: crying babies! the problem is, the meta codes are also echo-ed to CSV

Answer (score 1):

You could do it client side: open the file download in a new window and then redirect the current window with javascript.

Comment: Open new window is possible. you mean by AJAX call ? upon complete, then forward to next page by `window.location` ? but what if user disabled JavaScript ?

Comment: Something like this: <a target="_BLANK" href="download-link.php" onclick="location.href = next;">click here</a>. If there is no JS, you'll still get the download in the new window and the old window will be there, so you could put another regular link on the page for the user to get to the next page.

Comment: a smart method & a nice fallback.